# Module for form submitting straight to admin section

Tags: 7, forms, emails

Can anyone recommend a module for a contact form to submit to the administrator (so the administrator can view/read it)?

Users should be able to anonymously submit messages; they should not first log in, or create an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module.

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.